# ReactJS : How to wrap knockoutJS page inside React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, knockout.js, single-page-application

View (HTML)

```
<p>First name: <input data-bind="value: firstName" /></p>
<p>Last name: <input data-bind="value: lastName" /></p>
<h2><span data-bind="text: fullName"> </span>!</h2>
```

---

nameConcat.js  (KnockoutJS)

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Tom", "Haykens"));
```

---

React Component

```
class NameConcat extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
       ???
    );
  }
}
```

---

I am a ReactJS newbie. How do I display knockoutJS application pages from ReactJS components ? Rewriting KnockoutJS pages in ReactJS is not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my project the skeleton was designed in Durandel ,part of the reason I could not use the option of rewriting in React .

So here is what I had to use :

Case 1) - Want to bind a data in KO way

```
public observableVariable = Observable();

public binding() { // durandle lifecycle hook // observable declared with the class 
    reactDom.render(<span data-bind={`text: observableVariable `}></span>, document.getElementById('reactRoot'));
    }
```

Case 2) - Want to bind an already KO page to React and leave the DOM to be updated at real DOM .

```
public observableVariable = Observable();

public binding() { // durandle lifecycle hook // observable declared with the class 
    reactDom.render(<div data-bind={`compose: { model: '-- index page where the knockout binding is written --',activationData: { --Observable parameter--: --Observable data--}    }`}></div>, document.getElementById('reactRoot'));
    }
```

Case 3) - Template Binding

> // declare all the observable at the top
>
> // All These component can be sent anywhere from the react composed child

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `<!--ko widget: {
                        kind: '--index--',
                        name: 'sample comp',
// write all the observable dependencies here , 
                        id: 'sample Id'
                    } -->
                    <!-- /ko -->`}} />
```

Case 4) If you want to load regular react component using observable : I mean if you want some data maintained in observable to use in react.

Have an tracking object and keep the data in sync using Observable subscribe :

```
{
    self reactPropValue;
    self.selectedVals.subscribe(function (newValue: any) {
                    let val = ko.toJSON(newValue);
                    reactPropValue= ko.toJSON(selectedVals());
                });
}
```

Now you can pass this into react component as a prop and each time the observable changes the subscribe will make sure to get a new value , dont forget to wrap your reactDom in side an function and call on subscribe ,because by design it wont trigger a reload .

If you are not in durandel you might need to add the ko.applybinding yourself otherwise its fine .

Look out for the error message in the console window if you get any , There could be some .

Sorry if my answer is not properly formatted .